# Android same R layout id getting generated in two library

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an application which dependency on two libraries

- Library1
- Library2

In the both libraries generated R.java, have duplicate layout id.
So, whenever I try to inflate the view, I am getting the first library view. Is there a way to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the full library package name

```
R.layout.mylayout // Resolves based on the 'imports' section
com.mycompany.packagename.R.layout.mylayout // explicit package
```

Comment: It resolved the problem, earlier I was taking the int value of mylayout and then passing to inflater. In that case it was not working fine.